# Is it possible to pull multiple SNMP values from try..catch statements?

Tags: powershell, snmp

Is there a way to pull multiple SNMP values and update them as new values in PowerShell?
I have two different OIDs that I'm pulling from my UPS and I want those integer values saved to a database table.

This is my code

```
$UPS_Temp_oid = '1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.10.2.3.2.1.4.1'
$Battery_Load_oid = '.1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.1.4.2.3.0'

$sql = "SELECT temp, batteryload, upsid, ups_ip FROM ups WHERE ups_ip IS NOT NULL"
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql, $conn)
$rows = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

while ($rows.Read()) {
    $ups_id = $rows["upsid"]
    $ups_ip = $rows["ups_ip"].trim()
    $ups_temp = $rows["temp"]
    $battery_load = $rows["batteryload"]

    Write-Output $ups_id, $ups_ip, $ups_temp, $battery_load
    # Ping UPS
    $ping = New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
    $ping_reply = $ping.Send($ups_mgmt_ip) | select status

    # If success go call func SNMP
    if ($ping_reply.status -eq "Success") {
        try {
            $frm_snmp = Invoke-SNMPget $ups_ip $UPS_Temp_oid "community"
        } catch {
            Write-Host "$ups_mgmt_ip SNMP Get error: $_"
            return null
        }
```

would I have to create another `try..catch` for the battery_load_oid or would I just simply do something like that?

```
Invoke-SNMPget ups_ip $ups_temp_oid, $nattery_load_oid "community"
```

Comment: Looking at the [site](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Proxx.SNMP/1.0.1.2/Content/Invoke-SnmpGet.ps1) for `Invoke-SNMPget`, it accepts multiple OIDs for that parameter, so you should be able to pass both at once.

Comment: thank you! ^_^ I'll read more about it